# How In Laravel 8 with Tailwind CSS define backend.css which overwrite app.css?

Tags: laravel, webpack, tailwind-css

In a Laravel 8 / Tailwind CSS v2.1 application, I make different layouts. So in `webpack.mix.js, I have custom class files defined.

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/backend.css', 'public/css', [
        require("tailwindcss"),
    ])
    .postCss('resources/css/profile.css', 'public/css', [
        require("tailwindcss"),
    ])
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js')],
    });
```

Any of the `*.css` files have unique classes, but they all have some common classes. I want to define some common `app.css` with some common definitions, and say in `backend.css` to define:

```
.admin_main_color {
    @apply text-gray-300 bg-green-900;
}
```

**MODIFIED :**
as that is laravel project I have no HTML files, but blade.php file.
So I try in next steps :
In webpack.mix.js I added app.css :

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require("tailwindcss"),
    ])
    .postCss('resources/css/backend.css', 'public/css', [
        require("tailwindcss"),
    ])
    .postCss('resources/css/profile.css', 'public/css', [
        require("tailwindcss"),
    ])
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js')],
    });
```

In resources/views/layouts/backend.blade.php I added app.css (which is before of backend.css) :

```
<title id="app_title">{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/backend.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

In resources/css/app.css I have :

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {

    .app_main_color { // in some cases I need to possibility to overwrite class in frontend.css/backend.css
        @apply text-yellow-300 bg-red-900;
    }
```

But when I try in resources/css/backend.css :

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@import app.css;


@layer base {

    .test_class {
        @apply text-gray-300 bg-red-800;
    }

    /*.app_main_color {*/
    /*    @apply text-gray-300 bg-green-900;*/
    /*}*/
```

If to leave commented 3 lines above, I got error in the console :

```
 (23:31) /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/tAdsBack/resources/css/backend.css The `app_main_color` class does not exist. If you're sure that `app_main_color` exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are being properly processed before Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as `@apply` can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree.
```

Lines with :

```
@import app.css;
```

did not help. How can I do it? I hope I clearly explained what I want...

And that will overwrite the `admin_main_color` definition in `app.css.` Can I do this, and how?

**MODIFIED 2:**
In laravel5-7 with bootstrap I had file
resources/sass/_variables.scss
with defined variables and in file
resources/sass/app.scss
I had lines :

```
@import "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
@import 'variables';
```

Can I use similar way in my app? If yes, how ?

**MODIFIED 3  :**

```
@import app_main_color;
/*@import app_main_color from app.css;*/

@layer base {

    h3 {
        @apply text-xl font-bold;
        padding:4px;
    }
    h4 {
        @apply text-lg font-bold;
        padding:3px;
    }

    /*.app_main_color {*/
    /*    @apply text-gray-300 bg-green-900;*/
    /*}*/



    .admin_page_container_wrapper {
        @apply flex-1 justify-items-start justify-self-start app_main_color  p-1 m-0;
    }
```

but I got error :

```
(35:62) /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/tAdsBack/resources/css/backend.css The `app_main_color` class does not exist. If you're sure that `app_main_color` exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are being properly processed before Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as `@apply` can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree.

  33 | 
  34 |     .admin_page_container_wrapper {
> 35 |         @apply flex-1 justify-items-start justify-self-start app_main_color  p-1 m-0;
     |                                                              ^
  36 |     }
```

The sense of importing app_main_color is that it is used in other classes, like in definition of
admin_page_container_wrapper class, but I can not find how to makle it.

Comment: You should be able to do this, the primary point is to include them in your HTML as this: base definition, then custom definitions, that way you will overwrite them.

Comment: Plase look at MODIFIED

Comment: Plase look at MODIFIED 2

Answer (score 4):

If I need to compile two different CSS files using tailwindcss and also define new variables or classes, I would create app.css and backend.css and also main.css.

**main.css**:

```css
.app_main_color{
    @apply text-xl font-medium text-yellow-300 bg-red-900;
}
```

**app.css**:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base { 
    .new_class{
        @apply app_main_color text-green-400 ;
    }
}
```

**backend.css**:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
.app_main_color{
    @apply text-xl font-medium text-yellow-300 bg-green-900;
  }
}
@layer base { 
    .new_class{
    @apply app_main_color text-blue-400;
    }
}
```

Now to let app and backend use classes defined in main you need to add main as component to tailwind.config.js. You can do it by using [css-in-js-syntax](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#css-in-js-syntax) or load the main.css file as follows:

```js
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')
const fs = require("fs")
const postcss = require('postcss')
const postcssJs = require('postcss-js')
const css = fs.readFileSync("./resources/css/main.css", "utf8")
const parsedCss = postcss.parse(css)

const root = postcssJs.objectify(parsedCss)
module.exports = {
    purge: [
        './resources/**/*.blade.php',
        './resources/**/*.js',
        './resources/**/*.vue',
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Nunito', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
    },

    variants: {
    },

    plugins: [
        require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
        plugin(function ({ addComponents }) {
            addComponents(root)

        })
    ],
};
```

In app or backend files you can define new or change classes as backend is changing the
app_main_color class but app is just using it.

Also you don't need to include app and backend in html file at the same time. Load each per route.

Comment: In backend.css file class app_main_color is used in definitions of other classes of this file.
I would like if app_main_color is not defined in backend.css got its value from app.css.
Sorry, if did not put clearly what I want...
Maybe that is not possible?

Comment: Yes, but how to import app_main_color? Please look at MODIFIED 3

Comment: I modified file tailwind.config.js
except commented lines :
// require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
// require('postcss-import'),


as I do not use them in my app
But anyway I got error : s The `app_main_color` class does not exist
If I comment defintion of app_main_color - that is what I need .
Didi I missed something? 
Couul you please explain difference "@layer components { " and "@layer base { " ?
Is line :
@layer components {
    .app_main_color {

required in this place ?

Comment: @All, I want to create chat with  MHIdea. How can I do it here in this branch ?

Comment: that hack, making it a plugin and the custom loading stuff at the top, solved all my problems. kudos